# what is "read out"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Some species of tree have been read out of the party by
>   economics-minded foresters because they grow too slowly.

Could anyone tell me what "read out" means here? Obviously, it doesn't mean read somthing loudly.

Thanks.

Comment: Bottom line, "*read out of the party*" means "*excluded*" and is some kind of figurative usage, but why the author chose the verb *read* for preference with economists baffles me.

Comment: I found [this](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/read+out+of), it might help.

Comment: It's in [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/read#read__43) too.

Comment: I have honestly *never* come across this idiom. Never.

Comment: I've come across someone being read out of something (clubs, groups, that sort of thing), but it seems quite bizarre to me to use the phrase with reference to _trees_. It's not like trees are card-carrying members of some union that they can be expelled from. Perhaps the writer got _weed out_ and _read out_ confused and ended up with a kind of mixed idiom?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet If he meant _weed out_, how does the party figure into that? I think he did it intentionally, and is treating the trees as metaphorical members of the party.

Comment: Where did you find this quote? Could you post its link, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never heard about it, but maybe this has a political/religious [undertone](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=read):

> read out (v.) "expel by proclamation" (Society of Friends) is from
>   1788.

And the *Society of Friends* links to [that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quakers), the article on *Quakers*, a group of *Protestant* religious movements. The old [*Century*](http://triggs.djvu.org/century-dictionary.com/djvu2jpgframes.php?volno=06&page=546) has it too and gives the further example, similar to what was alluded to in the comments:

> [..]to read a person out of a political party.